# How does one use the SPIDev xfer command?

Tags: pi-3, python, spi

I can't figure out what the input/output of the SPIDev `xfer` command is supposed to be. I know it accepts an array of integers but what does it mean? I initially thought it meant the byte array of an integer like so:

```
Integer = 2
Byte Array = [0x0, 0x2]
```

But the SPI slave (a MSP432 microcontroller) receives two numbers: 80 and 0. Like the output of the `xfer` command is very random. So how do I use the `spidev.xfer` command?

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi.  If you transfer x bytes the device you are talking to receives x bytes and returns x bytes. If you send 0x0 and 0x2 it receives 0x0 and 0x2.  You need to read the device datasheet and study binary numbers.

Comment: Yeah, but the main problem is that my receiving device isn't receiving 0x0 and 0x2 - it's receiving random input instead and I don't know the cause.

Comment: Could be many reasons, an obvious one is incorrect connections.  You need to provide relevant information if you want help.

Comment: Okay so what I know is let's say I want to send an integer (for example, 2) over SPI - do I do spidev.xfer([0x0, 0x2])? Is this the correct format or is it  spidev.xfer([2])? Do I have to use a longer byte array?